# Specular Reflection of IR Light

Tags: visible-light, photons, thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation, camera

I have started to use thermal imaging cameras more and more and realized that I can see the reflection of my self bouncing off of a glass window through the IR camera. When viewing it on my monitor, I can see a clear and distinct reflection and wondered if it is because I, a human, is producing IR light actively throughout the day?

Comment: What is the wavelength range of the cameras?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Not just because you are a human being. In fact all objects with a non-zero temperature give of *thermal radiation* (which is not just infrared radiation). Thermal radiation includes all the electromagnetic rays given off by an object because of its temperature. This, among other wavelengths, includes infrared waves. You should check the wavelength spectrum of the light your camera is detecting to be sure it is in fact infra-red radiation being detected, and not other thermal radiation such as radio waves or even reflected UV light. Infrared waves are one component of the thermal radiation "spectrum".